# Chrome web extension DeclarativeNetRequest does not block intercept requests in main_frame

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, webrequest

I am migrating our v2 extension to manifest v3 and in the process of converting from the deprecated WebRequest API to the new DeclarativeNetRequest, I've found that the following rule does not intercept requests that originate while navigating through links, yet it does intercept the same request if the URL is entered into the address bar. I need it to intercept **all** requests and URL changes that happen in the top frame.

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": { "regexSubstitution": "some local web server address here" }
    },
    "condition": {
      "regexFilter": "^(https?\\://)?[^\\:]+$",
      "resourceTypes": [ "main_frame" ]
      
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Assuming you have permissions for both sites (the original page and the clicked link), it's a bug in Chrome which you can report on https://crbug.com

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it's a bug in Opera's requests originating from the Speed Dial shortcuts. Chromium Canary does not exhibit the same issue with the start page shortcuts.

I have reported the issue to the Opera team.